# Netbeans Structure Issue

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

So I created a java project in Netbeans and SQL am a bit of beginner to project creations. I created a form in `homepage.html` and created a file under source files called `homepage.java`. Note that the action in the form in `homepage.html` is to `homepage.java`.

Now, I want to create other files in the `homepage.java` to manipulate the information I made the user enter but am being unable to do so.
Here is what I have in `homepage.java`:

```
package Introduction;
package Introduction;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Homepage extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and
       <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    public void confirm(){

         try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
            out.println{"<h1>" + ("Anything") + "</h1>";}
    }



    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest
    request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String part = request.getParameter("part");
        String product = request.getParameter("product");
        String type = request.getParameter("type");
        String use = request.getParameter("use");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Homepage</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Part " + password + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }}
```

Comment: So whats the problem

Comment: The public void confirm part does not work and I have no idea why. Is there something huge I am missing? Shouldn't the form also print anything on submission. It prints the password as the processrequest part asks it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with first things first... close you class first...

Then add a `catch(){ }` block after the `try{ }` block. Because a `try{ }` block is always with atleast one `catch() { }` or `finally{ }` block.

For more.. Go to Javadocs...  [The try Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)